# header location not redirecting at once, looking for alternative

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I was writing a script where I have a redirect header in the end.

Then I added a redirect header in the middle if a specific condition would come up.

I was very surprised to notice that the last header("Location:http//mydomain.com") was the one that triggered. I thought that the header would automatically "jump" from the page, but it seems like it just keeps it in memory and goes through the whole page first.

Any ideas on what the "proper" way to "cut" the flow and change page is?

```
<?php
$specific_condition=true;
// I wanted this to be the end
if($specific_condition) header("Location: http://google.com/"); 
// But it still triggers following redirect
header("Location: http://bing.com/");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Always** call `exit;` right after your `Location` header:

```
if($specific_condition) {
    header("Location: http://google.com/"); 
    exit;
}
```

`header()` function by itself just collects the headers to be sent to the client. So it is not supposed to stop execution after any particular header, e.g. `Location`. But as long as it makes no sense to do something *after* you decided to redirect user - `exit` is used

Comment: fantastic, that solved it. Now I just have to wait 10 min to accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use variable to hold location address

This way, you can also execude some code after new location is set.

```
$location = 'http://bing.com/';
$specific_condition=true;   
if($specific_condition) $location = 'http://google.com';

//do something else
header("Location: " . $location);
```

Comment: `you can also execude some code after new location is set.` --- it is absolutely **MAKES NO SENSE**. You either decided to redirect, or not. No executing after, as long as it is not guaranteed to even finish processing

Comment: although this is good approach, the `exit` should be used anyway.

Comment: sure this works, but it's not what I was looking for. I was looking for a way to redirect without running any more of the code in the page, and exit did just that.